# StanfordCoreNLP: why two different data structures for cons. parse and dependency parse?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

Why Stanford:CoreNLP is using different data structures to represent its  trees (e.g. dep. trees with 'BasicDependenciesAnnotation' and cons. tree with 'TreeAnnotation')? 
It seems like these annotation are representable with the same data structure (like a DAG with labels). Is there any mechanism to cast these to each other? (at least for some of them)

LINK: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependency parses, when collapsed, are not necessarily DAGs. From the [Stanford Dependencies manual](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf):

> The collapsed and CCprocessed dependencies are not a DAG. The graphs can contain small cycles between two nodes (only). These don’t seem eliminable given the current representational choices. They occur with relative clauses such as *the woman who introduced you*. The cycles occur once you wish to represent the referent of *who*. In the basic plus extras representation, you get `rcmod(woman, introduced)`, `nsubj(introduced, who)`, and `ref(woman, who)`. In the collapsing process, ref arcs are collapsed, and so there is then a two node cycle: `rcmod(woman, introduced)` and `nsubj(introduced, woman)`.

Comment: Fair enough. But why different data structures for different dependencies?

Comment: Like  why all of these for different dependencies? "TreeAnnotation, BasicDependenciesAnnotation, CollapsedDependenciesAnnotation, CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation"

Comment: The latter three refer to different types of dependencies, each of which make sense for different use cases. See section 4 in the [dependencies manual](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf), "Different styles of dependency representation." All of these three have values which are `SemanticGraph` (directed graph) instances.